# Selecting a div with an ID and automatically clicking on it on page load with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div on my page with the ID of `#activateeditbutton`. I want this div to be automatically clicked when the page loads.

Here is the code I have written in jQuery, but it does not seem to work. If someone can point out my mistake I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#activateeditbutton').simulate('click');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $('#activateeditbutton').trigger('click');
    });
```

Comment: Wow... I was totally under the impression jQuery cannot preform user action... I feel dumb now haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**.trigger()**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
 $('#activateeditbutton').trigger('click');
```